# Beautiful Soup find_all() returning some results over and above the ones that meet the exact match criteria based on tag and class

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Pasting a simplified code snippet and output below

**CODE:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="columnGroup propFeatureHeader">FEATURES:</div><div     class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Architecture Style: </span><span class="featureName">Other</span></div><div class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Roof Type: </span><span class="featureName">Unknown</span>'
bs=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")    
RS = bs.find_all("div",{"class":"columnGroup"})
try:
    for item in RS:
        print("columnGroup")
        print(item)
        for FG, FN in zip(item.find_all("span",{"class":"featureGroup"}),item.find_all("span",{"class":"featureName"})):
            print("FG/FN", FG.text,FN.text)
except:
    print("error")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1 columnGroup
2 <div class="columnGroup propFeatureHeader">FEATURES:</div>
3 columnGroup
4 <div class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Architecture Style: </span><span class="featureName">Other</span></div>
5 FG/FN Architecture Style:  Other
6 columnGroup
7 <div class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Roof Type: </span><span class="featureName">Unknown</span></div>
8 FG/FN Roof Type:  Unknown
```

The question is why is the first Column group returned in the result set of the  `bs.find_all("div",{"class":"columnGroup"})`. Its class is 
`class="columnGroup propFeatureHeader"`

Also, is there some technique to avoid this columnGroup being returned in the ResultSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup splits the multi-valued `class` attribute into a list. Have a look at [this section in the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) for further details.

> When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class, you’re matching against *any* of its CSS classes.

For demonstration, have a look at the following snippet:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="columnGroup propFeatureHeader">...</div>', 'html.parser')
>>> soup.div['class']
['columnGroup', 'propFeatureHeader']
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="columnGroup">...</div>', 'html.parser')
>>> soup.div['class']
['columnGroup']
```

So, if you search only for `columnGroup`, it will match all the tags that have `columnGroup` as one of its classes. To get the tags that have `columnGroup` as its only class, you can use any one of the following:

[**CSS Selector:**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
RS = bs.select('div[class="columnGroup"]')
print(RS)
# [<div class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Architecture Style: </span><span class="featureName">Other</span></div>, <div class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Roof Type: </span><span class="featureName">Unknown</span></div>]
```

**`find_all()` with [custom function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):**

```
RS = bs.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag['class'] == ['columnGroup'])
print(RS)
# [<div class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Architecture Style: </span><span class="featureName">Other</span></div>, <div class="columnGroup"><span class="featureGroup">Roof Type: </span><span class="featureName">Unknown</span></div>]
```